# VB.NET Import of type 'ISupportInitialize' from assembly or module 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll' failed

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have been having this issue with a VB.NET project I am upgrading currently. I have looked through many solutions, but cannot find the exact cause. My working assumption at the moment is that the current version of a number of DLLs either do not have the type or it has been redefined in some way. This is quite an old project, I believe it is from 2012.

The most perplexing thing to me is that in this image:
[image: code snippet]

Where ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize is working on one line, but not in the next. This is doubly weird as the syntax highlighting is working, which is telling me that the interpreter can find the type somewhere.

I have tried removing the old references and adding new ones, adding older versions from nuget, and trying an older version of visual studio (both 2019 and 2015 have been tested).

For reference here is the errors from the console:
[image: error console]

This is failing on a number of DLLs with the exact same .NET error code, so I suspect it is all the same issue.

If there is any additional information that could help, please let me know and I will grab it.

Comment: "System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll" is the .Net Core assembly. Are you mixing .Net Core and .Net Framework assembly references?

Comment: When I imported the solution into vs2015, it said there was a missing reference to this DLL. I thought this was weird but jumped on nuget and installed the reference I found on there.

Would this be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I am still not 100% sure what the issue is exactly. But my guess is that it was either because I was running the dev environment through Terminal Server, or I was using the incorrect version of DevExpress.

As I did both changes at once I cannot be certain, but moving to a local Dev environment and installing an older version of DevExpress (v15.2.20) has solved my issue.

Thanks to TnTinMn for trying to help!